# gradle command line, no details on build failure

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I started recently on Android and after losing my patience with build times on Android Studio, decided to try command line option(initial reading on internet indicated 50% reduction in time required). I was able to install apk to the device and even launch an activity from command line.

On speed, felt like some improvement...

I was happy to have learnt something new and understand more about gradle until I made a change in layout and forgot to include the id in the ids.xml. gradle command wont reveal the file in which the error exists(id not assigned) but indicates the line number and resource name.

Given below is the error:

```
:TestProject:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
:TestProject:processDebugResources
 Position 68:21-44 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/FrameLayoutOuter').

:TestProject:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Following is the command that was tried

```
gradlew assembledebug
```

If I compile the same project using Android Studio it shows all the details including the file name for me to act on. Using --info or --debug or --stacktrace does not change anything from command line.

Anyone else noticed this.. Is this a bug or I am missing something?

And I got the following option

**UPDATE 1**
Adding Android Studio output

- From Messages Gradle Build

  C:\src\TRUNK\mobileapps\android\TestProject\res\layout\activity_framed.xml
  Error:(68, 21) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/FrameLayoutOuter').
- Gradle Console Output

  :Testproject:processDebugResources
  AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"No resource found that matches the given name (at \u0027id\u0027 with value \u0027@id/FrameLayoutOuter\u0027).","sourcePath":"C:\src\TRUNK\mobileapps\android\TestProject\res\layout\activity_framed.xml","position":{"startLine":68,"startColumn":21,"startOffset":2499,"endColumn":44,"endOffset":2522},"original":""}

Comment: *No resource found that matches the given name at 'id' with value '@id/FrameLayoutOuter'*

Comment: This is not complete information as I mentioned, would like to know which file has this issue? Android studio is able to give me the file name as well